clean unnecessary data in database table with 100M+ rows
I have a table named Controllers which has records of some devices with unique IMEI number.



Field
Type
Null
Key
Default
Extra




id
int
NO
PRI
NULL
auto_increment


device_name
varchar(200)
NO

NULL



device_location
text
NO

NULL



imei_number
varchar(15)
NO

NULL



voltage
decimal(10,2)
NO

0.00



current
decimal(10,2)
NO

0.00



temperature
decimal(10,2)
NO

0.00



fault
int
NO

0



created_at
timestamp
NO

CURRENT_TIMESTAMP



updated_at
timestamp
NO

CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
DEFAULT_GENERATED on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP



I have another table named Logs which stores logs of each device. The logs are inserted every 10 seconds from each device and now RMSLogs table has 100M+ rows



Field
Type
Null
Key
Default
Extra




id
int
NO
PRI
NULL
auto_increment


imei_number
varchar(15)
NO

NULL



voltage
decimal(10,2)
NO

0.00



current
decimal(10,2)
NO

0.00



temperature
decimal(10,2)
NO

0.00



fault
tinyint
NO

0



created_at
timestamp
NO

CURRENT_TIMESTAMP



updated_at
timestamp
NO

CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
DEFAULT_GENERATED on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP



I want to delete the rows which have a time difference less than 10 minutes with respect to imei_number.
I tried these steps:
STEP-1
Using a simple delete query.
DELETE t1
FROM RMSLogs t1
JOIN RMSLogs t2 ON t1.id = t2.id + 1
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, t2.created_at, t1.created_at) < 10;


When I executed the query, it affected around no more than 8500 rows and took around 2 minutes.
STEP-2
Using a stored procedure.
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteLogsLessThan10Minutes()
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE imei_number VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE curr_timestamp DATETIME;
    DECLARE previous_timestamp DATETIME;
    
    -- Declare cursor to fetch distinct IMEI numbers from RmsController table
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT imei_number FROM RMSController;
    
    -- Declare continue handler for cursor
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    
    OPEN cur;
    
    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO imei_number;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;
        
        -- Temporary table to hold log entries for the current IMEI number
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Temp_Logs (
            created_at DATETIME
        );
        
        -- Insert log entries for the current IMEI number into the temporary table
        INSERT INTO Temp_Logs (created_at)
        SELECT created_at
        FROM RMSLog
        WHERE imei_number = imei_number
        ORDER BY created_at;
        
        -- Initialize variables for timestamp comparison
        SET previous_timestamp = NULL;
        
        -- Loop through the log entries for the current IMEI number
        WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Temp_Logs) > 0 DO
            SELECT MIN(created_at) INTO curr_timestamp FROM Temp_Logs;
            
            IF previous_timestamp IS NOT NULL AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, previous_timestamp, curr_timestamp) < 10 THEN
                -- Delete the log entry if the time difference is less than 10 minutes
                DELETE FROM RMSLog
                WHERE imei_number = imei_number AND created_at = curr_timestamp;
            END IF;
            
            SET previous_timestamp = curr_timestamp;
            
            -- Remove the processed log entry from the temporary table
            DELETE FROM Temp_Logs WHERE created_at = curr_timestamp;
        END WHILE;
        
        -- Drop the temporary table
        DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS Temp_Logs;
        
    END LOOP;
    
    CLOSE cur;
    
END //

DELIMITER ;


When I executed this stored procedure it resulted in a timeout.

It seems highly unlikely that your STEP-1 would achieve anything close to what you want, as it is joining on consecutive ids with no consideration for imei_number - db<>fiddle. Given the result of the final select in that fiddle, which rows should be deleted?

hey @user1191247, say I have a device with IMEI no. 2, and it has multiple logs every minute, but I want logs of every 5 minute, less than that should get deleted
like here, https://dbfiddle.uk/D81JGwHA , 3rd, 4th, 5th, 6th and 8th row should get deleted

One approach is to organise the rows into 5 minute buckets per imei_number and delete all but the first row per bucket, something like this db<>fiddle. This will result in some cases where the interval between two rows may be less than five minutes, but there will only be one row per five minute bucket. Would that work for you?

Got "no space left on device" when used partition

For purging data, walk through the table using the PRIMARY KEY in chunks of 1000.  For each 1000, delete what you can.  More:  https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig
For other shrinking of the table,

Use smaller datatypes where practical.  Surely, no temp will ever bey as high as 99999999.99!  That takes 5 bytes.  DECIMAL(5,2) takes only 3 bytes.
imei_number can probably be DECIMAL(15,0) which takes 7 bytes instead of `VARCHAR(...), which takes 17 bytes.
Normalize.  I would guess that location is being repeated a lot.
Do you really need updated_at?  (TIMESTAMP is 5 bytes.)
More:  https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_sensor

If you will be saving only the last N days of data, consider Partitioning as an efficient way of deleting old data.
